# What is the pythonic way to extract values from dict

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best way to extract values from dictionary. Let's suppose we have a list of dicts:

```
projects = [{'project': 'project_name1', 
             'dst-repo': 'some_dst_path', 
             'src-repo': 'some_src_path', 
             'branches': ['*']},
            {...}, 
            {...}]
```

Now I just iterate through this dictionary and get values, something like:

```
   for project in projects:
       project_name = project.get('project')
       project_src = ....
       project_dst = ....
       ....
       ....
```

So the question is: "Are there any more pythonic approaches to extract values by key from dictionary that allow not making so many lines of code for new variable assignment?"

Comment: Your "something like" code makes no sense; each iteration will overwrite the variables. What exactly are you trying to do with this data, and why can't you just leave it in the dicts?

Comment: You could extract the variables in a single line, but that's not necessarily "more pythonic" `project_name, project_src =  project.get('project'), project.get('src-repo')...`

Comment: But why do you want to assign all the values in the dict to the variable when those values are already present in the dict?

Comment: Actually in this FOR loop section I have a rather big chunk of code instead those ... .... (dots) and I just don't want to use `project.get('project')` everywhere in order to get name of project. So in this case I want to make my code without line wrappers and more readable.

Comment: And why do you use `get`? `project['project']` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but you can make it more compact by using a list comprehension to extract the values from the current dictionary. Eg,

```
projects = [
    {
        'project': 'project_name1', 
        'dst-repo': 'some_dst_path', 
        'src-repo': 'some_src_path', 
        'branches': ['*']
    },
]

keys = ['project', 'src-repo', 'dst-repo', 'branches']
for project in projects:
    name, src, dst, branches = [project[k] for k in keys]
    # Do stuff with the values
    print(name, src, dst, branches)
```

**output**

```
project_name1 some_src_path some_dst_path ['*']
```

However, this approach gets unwieldy if the number of keys is large.

---

If keys are sometimes absent from the dict, then you will need to use the `.get` method, which returns `None` for missing keys (unless you pass it a default arg):

```
name, src, dst, branches = [project.get(k) for k in keys]
```

If you need specific default for each key, you could put them into a dict, eg

```
defaults = {
    'project': 'NONAME',
    'src-repo': 'NOSRC',
    'dst-repo': 'NODEST',
    'branches': ['*'],
}

projects = [
    {
        'project': 'project_name1', 
        'src-repo': 'some_src_path', 
    },
]

keys = ['project', 'src-repo', 'dst-repo', 'branches']
for project in projects:
    name, src, dst, branches = [project.get(k, defaults[k]) for k in keys]
    # Do stuff with the values
    print(name, src, dst, branches)
```

**output**

```
project_name1 some_src_path NODEST ['*']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = [elt.values() for elt in projects]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
   for project in projects:
       project_name = project['project']
       project_src = ....
       project_dst = ....
       ....
       ....
```

I'm not sure you can get less typing

//EDIT:
Ok, it looks I misunderstood the question:
Assume we have a list of dicts like this:

```
projects = [ {'project': "proj1", 'other': "value1", 'other2': "value2"},
             {'project': "proj2", 'other': "value3", 'other2': "value4"},
             {'project': "proj2", 'other': "value3", 'other2': "value4"} ]
```

To extract the list of `project` fields, you can use the following expression:

```
projects_names =  [x['project'] for x in projects]
```

This will iterate over project list, extracting the value of 'project' key from each dictionary.

Comment: You could give the variables single letter names but I'm not sure Code Golf is the OP's aim here.

Comment: @Sayse: It looks like the SO community doesn't forgive. Wanted to help, got tons of minuses.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the OP doesn't want a list of project names. On each loop they need to get all the values from the current dict from `projects`.

Comment: Try not to think of the downvotes as rejection, they just mean that (at least) 4 people do not agree with you (I didn't downvote either, but I don't think this is a suitable answer)